# How can I refrence a project in another one in xcode?

Tags: xcode

Xcode 4.2
Now I have two project name with "game.xcodeproj" and "core.xcodeproj"
I want refrence all "core" files and resource in "game".
Now I drag "core" into "game" project without copy. But it can't read "core" head file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add a path to "core" head file into the "Header Search Paths" in Build Settings of "game" project. Maybe, `$(SRCROOT)/core.h` or absolute path, doesn't matter. And switch to `YES` option "Always Search User Paths"